# How do I dynamically create a list in which each line has to have a certain format?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, list

I need to dynamically create a list in JavaScript with a unique div id for each line. How do I do this?

**HTML**
The HTML code:

```
 <ul class="sub-menu insert">
```

The ul class I am working with is "insert"

### *The JavaScript code has two functions:*

**The first JavaScript function**

```
$(function() {
   $.ajax({
       type: 'GET',
       url: 'json/data.json',
       async: false,
       beforeSend: function() {
       },
       dataType: 'json',
       success: function(result) {
          $(document).ready(function() {
          var divsToAppend = "";
          $.each(result, function(i) { //Item key
             $("#insert").append += '<li id="' + i + '">"<a href="#"><div id="test_ID"' + i +'></div></a>" + '</li>');
          });
       });
   }
});
```

Code snippet:
This is a String:

```
    "<a href="#"><div id="test_ID" + i +></div></a>"
```

The first function one loops trough a JSON file, the intention is that it shall create a list, with as many lines as there is in the mentioned file. Each line in the list has to follow a certain syntax. And tt has to generate a unique div id for each line. The list connects with the ul class "insert" in the HTML code.

I want the generated list to look like this in HTML:

```
<li><a href="#"><div id="test_ID1"></div></a></li> 
<li><a href="#"><div id="test_ID2"></div></a></li>
```

The unique div id that I mentioned:

```
"test_IDi"
```

**The second JavaScript function**

The second function connects with the unique "test_id" that is generated in the first function. It collects data from the JSON file. It works, but only when there is a single "div id". It has to be able to distinguish between the different unique "div id:s" that is generated by the first function.

```
$(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'json/data.json',
        async: false,
        beforeSend: function () {/*loading*/
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (result) {
            $("#test_IDi").empty(); //Empty ID 

        $.each(result, function(i, v) {

            $("#test_IDi").append('<li id="' + v.id + '">' + v.test + '  ' + v.testDate + '</li>');
        });
        }
    });
});
});
```

The JSON File (included for reference):

```
 [
   {"id": "a", "test": "Java", "testDate": "17-08-01"},
   {"id": "b","test":"JavaScript","testDate": "17-08-02"}
 ]
```

How I wish that the finished list will look:

Java 17-08-01

JavaScript 17-08-02

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go.

Look at the below example:

```js
var result = [{
  data: ''
}, {
  data: ''
}];

var jsonData = [{
  "id": "a",
  "test": "Java",
  "testDate": "17-08-01"
}, {
  "id": "b",
  "test": "JavaScript",
  "testDate": "17-08-02"
}];

$.each(result, function(index) {

  $(".insert").append('<li><a href="#"><div id="test_ID' + index + '"></div></a></li>');
});

$.each(jsonData, function(index, value) {

  $("#test_ID" + index).append('<li id="' + value.id + '">' + value.test + '  ' + value.testDate + '</li>');
});

$('#output-html').val($('#html-data').html());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="html-data">
  <ul class="sub-menu insert">
  </ul>
</div>

<div>
  Output HTML:
  <textarea id="output-html" rows="10" cols="55"></textarea>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I got a lot of valuable help from Gaurav to solve this. After I had worked a little more on the code I found a way to reduce it by removing "test_id", instead of adding the code from the second function directly to the loop that generates a new list element.

```
$(function() {
 $.ajax({
     type: 'GET',
     url: 'json/data.json',
     async: false,
     beforeSend: function() {

     },
     dataType: 'json',
     success: function(result) {

         $(document).ready(function() {

             $.each(result, function(i, v) {

                 $(".insert").append('<li><a href="#">' + v.test + '</div></a></li>');
             });
         });
     }
  });
});
```

Comment: Great job! ;). It's always a pleasure to look at the optimization and more importantly the attitude of one person while solving the problem and putting that extra effort. I guess we are, as a community here to make world a nicer place. P. S: I always follow one simple rule while I'm coding/designing/experimenting and that's CODE FIRST OPTIMIZE LATER.